# GWT 2.7 errors after upgrade: method cast is undefined

Tags: gwt

I just upgraded from GWT 2.6 to 2.7. No errors in Eclipse but when I debug with superdevmode the compile to JavaScript now throws hordes of errors. A prominent one is of this type: This line:

```
final HttpServletResponse response = HttpServletResponse.class.cast( servletResponse );
```

...now throws "The method cast(ServletRequest) is undefined for the type Class.

It works if I change the line to

```
final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse ;
```

...but before wholesale changes it would be nice to know why it quit working!

Another prominent one is that it now complains that I need a < source > directive for my server-side stuff because it's not living underneath a subpackage called 'client'.

Any insights on either of these are much appreciated. Thanks-

Comment: I think the problem is that it's trying to compile my server-side stuff. Exact same project with GWT 2.6 did not. Anybody have insights on how it decides what to compile in 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

In general stay away from reflection or anything complex that is unlikely to be in JavaScript. I always fix errors when I upgrade, but I am grateful to the GWT team for making it better. If they removed support for something questionable, it is all for the best. I'll do any amount of refactoring necessary to work with a newer and better version. As far, as <source> respect conventions and be explicit.